# Class level variable in Spring Batch processor

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading data from StoredProcedureCusrsorReader. The data is for multiple accounts and having one-to-many relationships. So for each account I am getting the output as for each account I have multiple order. I don't want to process the order until I detect a change in the Account number

**AccountNo  PurchaseOrder

- 1           AB1
- 1           AB2
  -1           AB3
  -2           CD1
  -2           CD2
  -2           CD3**

In the processor I want to aggregate the records with same account no using code like this

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class CashFlowProcessor implements ItemProcessor<BankTransaction, MonthlyCashFlow> {

    private LocalDate lastDate = null;
    private List<BankTransaction> monthlyGroup = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public MonthlyCashFlow process(BankTransaction transaction) {
        if (lastDate == null || isSameMonth(transaction.getDate())) {
            monthlyGroup.add(transaction);
            lastDate = transaction.getDate();
            return null;
        }
        //this means that a new month has started
        MonthlyCashFlow cashFlow = aggregate(); // aggregate the collected flows
        lastDate = transaction.getDate(); //set the new month
        monthlyGroup = new ArrayList<>(); // create a new list
        monthlyGroup.add(transaction);
        return cashFlow;
    }
}
```

But the class level variable lastDate is always null for each record getting processed. Pleas suggest.

Comment: Well, this means `isSameMonth` is false for all records that you have processed. Otherwise you should debug and see if it is ever set.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. That was the case as you pointed and I am able to track the class level variable now.